# No agregar android en compilación ionic

Tags: android-studio, ionic4

estoy desarrollando una app con ionic 4 y angular, y al compilar ejecuto

```
ionic build
npx cap add android
npx cap open android
```

La segunda línea crea el proyecto android en la carpeta del proyectio ionic, mi pregunta es, cuando hago alg{un cambio en mi proyecto, y vuelvo a compilar, siempre tengo que eliminar la carpeta android y volver a ejecutar:

npx cap add android

O hay alguna forma de hacer el build y no tenes q ejecutar el add android y el open android, ya que el android studio ya lo tengoa abierto, garcias.

Answer (score 0):

Al final pude solucionarlo:

Si hacemos npx add android, agregaremos la carpeta del proyecto android. Si por ejemplo hacemos un cambio simple en el código del proyecto, para no tener que agregar toda la carpeta, hacemos
`npx cap copy Android`: Copia los archivos compilados de Angular al proyecto de Android

Previamente debimos haber compilado el proyecto.Saludos.